# Funcion con Array en C

Tags: array, c

*Hacer una función que reciba como parámetro un arreglo y la cantidad de elementos (válidos) cargados en él y los muestre por pantalla*

Hace todo lo que pide el enunciado. Carga la cantidad de arreglos que le digo, pero no se como tengo que hacer para cargarle valores a los arrays.
Si alguien me explica como hay que hacerlo lo agradezco mucho, porque estoy muy perdido :D

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void showArray(int a[], int validos);

int main(){
    int valido=0, vec[5];

    printf("Cuantos valores va a meter?\n");
    scanf("%d", &valido);

    showArray(vec, valido);

    return 0;
}


void showArray(int *a, int validos){
    printf("Mostrando el arreglo de int...\n");
    for(int x=0;x<validos;x++){
        printf("[%d]", a[x]);
    }
}
```

Por ejemplo, si le digo que meta 10 valores, me devuelve en consola esto:

```
Cuantos valores va a meter?
10
Mostrando el arreglo de int...
[8] - [0] - [65] - [0] - [12784592] - [0] - [16] - [10] - [12784560] - [0] -
```

Comment: Que esperabas que sucediera? Si le diste un tamaño de 5, y quieres leer 10? Estas accediendo a memoria que no te corresponde, entonces vas a tener valores basura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesantemente, lo que te regresa cuando no cargas un arreglo es basura de la memoria. Para cargar el arreglo tendrías que poner otro scanf() que reciba valores separados, por ejemplo, por comas

```
char[250] str;
scanf("%s", str);
```

luego tendrás que dividir tu string:

```
char* tokens = strtok(str, ","); //En caso de dividir por comas
```

Ten en cuenta que los valores siguen siendo strings, por lo que tendrás que transformar los strings en ints por lo que tendrás que usar una función int atoi(char* input); para ello.

```
int count = 0;
for(count = 0; count < 5; count++){
    vec[count++] = atoi(*tokens++); //donde *tokens++ te permite recorrer el arreglo de valores tokenizados
}
```